# Auto inserting SPMetal child entities?

Tags: spmetal

Let's say I have two lists in my web site, linked by a lookup :

- List A (content type ACT)

  - Title (text)
- List B (content type BCT)

  - Title (text)
  - A (lookup to A)

I use SPMetal to generate a DataContext. SPMetal will generates class like this (pseudo code for readability) :

```
public class ACT
{
     public string Title { get; set;}
     public EntityList<BCT> B { get; set; }
}

public class BCT
{
     public string Title { get; set;}
     public EntityRef<ACT> A { get; set; }
}
```

and that's OK.

Now I want to add some B entities to on existing A object. If I use :

```
using(var ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
     var myA = ctx.A.Where(a=>a.Id = theIdFromSomewhere).Single();

     var newB = new BCT{
         A = myA,
         Title = "I am your father"
     }

     myA.B.Add(newB);

     ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This code won't throw any exception, but the newB entity won't be created on the sharepoint site.

If I want to fix, I have to add `ctx.B.Add(newB)` just before the call to submitchanges. And that fix the issue.

However, while it's very simple in my case because I do have the context available, how can I automatically mark new child entities to be inserted?

To illustrate my issue, imagine I'm somewhere in a deep nested sequence of utility method that waits for a ACT parameter :

```
public static void MyVeryUsefulMethod(ACT myA)
{
     var newB = new BCT{
         A = myA,
         Title = "You don't know the power of the Dark Side"
     }

     myA.B.Add(newB);
}
```

In this case, I don't have access to the context object.

I can see some workarounds :

1. Return the newly created newB object by changing the method signature to `public static BCT MyVeryUsefulMethod(ACT A)` and let the caller add the new entity object to the context. This works, but I still have to flow the newly created object through the whole stack until I reach the method that created the context.
2. pass the context through all methods calls (`public static void MyVeryUsefulMethod(MyDataContext ctx, ACT A)`. This can also works, but a lot of noisy parameters in my specific object model.
3. Inject the Context as a property of generated classes. I don't know how to it unfortunately
4. Store the context object in `[ThreadStatic]` static variable wrapped in a static property. This may works, but seems a bit tweaky
5. throw off SPMetal into the void and write my own mapping framework. This looks like seductive, as the more I use SPMetal the more I feel it's unreliable (especially when working with content types in VS). In fact, I think I'm not using the right tool. SPMetal looks like more suited for client/server scenario than for custom application coding.

I'd appreciate you share your feelings and experience.